# Mouse Hover drop down with gwtbootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, gwtbootstrap3

I am new to gwt-Bootstrap and currently I am trying to replicate an interface that is built with regular bootstrap, html and css. The application on which I am trying to develop the UI is a gwt application and hence I am trying to implement gwtbootstrap3 to develop the UI.

I can't really find a way to replicate the Mouse Hover dropdown on the nav bar with gwtbootstrap3. Isn't there any pre-built java code for a mouse hover action? if there isn't, then can I import self written java files for mouse hover actions and use a different namespace in between gwtbootstrap3 namespace? Please help.

thanks